# IOS10 - Using a CollectionView inside a custom inputView

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, swift3

I'm trying to have a custom password input with the digits from 0 to 9 and some empty keys placed randomly like this :

[image]

Here are my simple UICollectionViewCell

```
class KeyboardKeyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var mLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and my UIView that holds the UICollectionView (as a test I'm only trying with 3 cells)

```
import UIKit
protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(character: String)
}

class PasswordKeyboard: UIView , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    func initializeSubviews() {
        let lBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let lKeyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "PasswordKeyboard", bundle: lBundle)
        let lCellNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardKeyCollectionViewCell", bundle: lBundle)
        let lKeyboardNibView = lKeyboardNib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        self.addSubview(lKeyboardNibView)
        lKeyboardNibView.frame = self.bounds

        mCollectionView.dataSource = self
        mCollectionView.delegate = self

        mCollectionView.register(lCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "idgaf")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
   {
        return 3
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "idgaf", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! KeyboardKeyCollectionViewCell
        cell.mLabel.text = String(describing: indexPath.item) //TODO Randomize this
        return cell
   }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "idgaf", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! KeyboardKeyCollectionViewCell
        self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(character: cell.mLabel.text!)

    }
}
```

And the ViewController with the textfield that will use that custom keyboard

```
class LoginController: UiViewController  , KeyboardDelegate
{
    func keyWasTapped(character: String) {
        passwordField.insertText(character)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let keyboardView = PasswordKeyboard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 300))
        keyboardView.delegate = self 
        passwordField.inputView = keyboardView

    }
}
```

What I've currenly done doesn't crash my app , the view appears as it should and the delegate is called is it should however I lose the reference of the cell I clicked on .

I got some log from the debugger during the creation of the cells :

[image]

And after tapping the first cell :

[image]

I've been trying to fix this issue but I can't find what's causing this. Thanks for reading until this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead dequeuing the cell in your selection delegate method , try this way to get the cell.

```
func cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
     let cell = cellForItem(indexPath) as! KeyboardKeyCollectionViewCell
    self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(character: cell.mLabel.text!)

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: more info https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem